# How to display an image in a carousel with firebase storage

Tags: angular, firebase-storage

I am attempting to display some images in a carousel. Those images are stored in a firebase bucket and I have to use the getDownloadURL() method to get the URL to display. This means that when the carousel is created, those URLs are not yet valid as they have not been recovered from firebase.

I tried having a flag that is false until the data is received from my database, but this does not account for the additional call to the firebase system to get a valid URL. I don't see any way to use the async pipe here either. The "carouselUrls" variable holds the valid URLs.

```
<div fxLayout="column" 
     class="mt-32"
     flex="45%"
     style="width:40%; margin:0px 5%">

     <mat-carousel
         timings="250ms ease-in"
         [autoplay]="true"
         interval="5000"
         [slides]="currentDesign.marketplace.images.length"
         [loop]="true"
         orientation="ltr" >

            <mat-carousel-slide
                #matCarouselSlide
                *ngFor="let slide of carouselUrls; let i = index"
                [image]="slide"
                overlayColor="#00000040"
                [hideOverlay]="false">

            </mat-carousel-slide>
    </mat-carousel>
```

The problem is simple. There doesn't seem to be a viable method to pause the creation of the carousel until all of those calls to firebase have returned valid URLs and you therefore get a blank carousel.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can hide it with `ngIf`?

```
<div *ngIf="carouselUrls?.length"
     fxLayout="column" 
     class="mt-32"
     flex="45%"
     style="width:40%; margin:0px 5%">
```

Comment: I tried several variations of that. I even hid it with an ngIf that had a simple 10 second delay with the hopes of ensuring that all observables resolved before the item was created. No luck